# Allow validation to domain name after two dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a regex which helps validate email and I would like to allow my email to have two dots on the domain name.
Example. 
xxxxx@yyy.zzzz.se

This is the regex

```
'/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z]{2,10}$/'
```

I tried adding,

```
+(?<!\.)
```

before the ending '$' but it allowed me to add way to many dots, not just two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match two of these:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.]
```

Full regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.]){1,2}[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$/
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the dot near the end and what follows in a group, and repeat that group once or twice:

```
^[\w.!#$%&’*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z]{2,10}){1,2}$
```

(enable the case-insensitive flag for more terseness, and use `\w` instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_` in the character set for the same reason)

https://regex101.com/r/o0pzoC/3